# I am taken to "www.google.com" after sign in with google cordova

Tags: ionic3, firebase-authentication, cordova-plugins, google-signin

I am trying to do google plus native firebase authentication. When i click my login button it asks me to choose account and after that. Instead of redirecting me to the app it takes me to "www.google.com"

I have tried clicking "Done" after it takes me to "www.google.com".
It then closes the popup and says "the user cancelled the operation".
What do please

**Here is my sign in code**

```
googleNativeLogin() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.googlePlus.login(
          {
          'webClientId': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          'scopes': '',
          'offline': true
        }
        ).then((response) => {
          const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(response.idToken);
          firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
            .then((user) => {
              this.presentToast(user)
              resolve(user);
            }).catch((err) =>{
              reject(err);
            });
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
           this.presentToast(err)

        });
    })
  }
```

I want to be redirected to the app after i choose an account. I dont want to be taken to "www.google.com"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello I was facing this issue and this helped me out I hope it works for you too
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/issues/565#issuecomment-499862324